# How to implement spannable more than once in the following code?

Tags: android, recursion, settext, spannable

##As spannable can't access data from outside of onclick listener, the whole code is written inside on click listener##

rd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int clicked=0;
            clicked++;    //< click counter>


            String extract=tv2.getText().toString();
            int startIndex=tv2.getSelectionStart();
            int endIndex=tv2.getSelectionEnd();
            extract=extract.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager=      (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboardManager.setText(extract);  // <Textview selection and clipboard >



            int length = extract.length();

            Spannable spannable=new SpannableString(extract);

            spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, length, 0);
                      // spannable to set the background color

            String nsb98=tv2.getText().toString();
            int length2=nsb98.length();
            String nsb97=nsb98.substring(0,startIndex);
            String nsb96=nsb98.substring(endIndex,length2);
            tv2.setText(TextUtils.concat(nsb97, spannable,nsb96));//
```

<>

```
            if (clicked>0){    }   }
```

Comment: and your problem is... ?

Comment: When I select a portion of textview and click the rd button, then its highlighted. But it works for 1 time only. If I try highlighting another portion then the first spannable is reset and the new spannable is highlighted.  As i have spannable can store one one startIndex and endindex. How to make it a loop so that multiple startIndex and endIndex can be stored and hence multiple highlighting is possible?

Comment: To make the question more clear please add your above comment to the question body, also it will be better if you replace 'the following code' with 'EditText'

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your `onClick()`, and it should give you the desired result.

```
Editable text = tv2.getText();
Spannable raw = new SpannableString(text);
BackgroundColorSpan[] spans = raw.getSpans(0, raw.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);

final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text.toString());

for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
    sb.setSpan(span, text.getSpanStart(span), text.getSpanEnd(span), text.getSpanFlags(span));
}
sb.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), tv2.getSelectionStart(), tv2.getSelectionEnd(), 0);

tv2.setText(sb);
```